# SonarQube Error: "The first field does not define a resource pattern" even when no exclusion is set?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am working on SonarQube integration with the projects in our company, most of the project integrates well without any problem.

There's one project keeps on failing at (Complete the SonarQube Analysis) build step, and I suspect this is the cause:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Exclusions > Issues : Invalid format. The first field does not define a resource pattern: ,csharpsquid:S134,*
```

`,csharpsquid:S134,*` looks like a 3 part string delimited by comma, I have no idea why the first part is missing as we have not set any issue exclusion(from web or properties) for csharpsquid:S134.

Enabling /d:sonar.verbose=true does not give much information either.
We don't want csharpsquid:S134 to be excluded either as we have found some violations on csharpsquid:S134 in other projects.

We are using:

- Java 8 on both SonarQube server and scanner
- SonarQube Version 6.2
- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0
- Sonar C# 6.1.0.2359

Also, we have just migrated from H2 to Azure sql server 2014 if that matters?

Full Stack Trace:

```
2017-07-26T05:18:22.3083489Z ##[error]22:18:22.208 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3083489Z ##[error]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3093524Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3093524Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3093524Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:272)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3103529Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3103529Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3113493Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3113493Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3113493Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3123494Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3123494Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3133537Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3133537Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3143546Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3143546Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3143546Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3153539Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3153539Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3163510Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3163510Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3163510Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3173492Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3173492Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3183535Z ##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3183535Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3193555Z ##[error]at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3193555Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3193555Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3203496Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3203496Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3203496Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3213508Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ModuleIssues

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3213508Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3223544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3223544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3223544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3233556Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3233556Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3243504Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3243504Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3243504Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3253547Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3253547Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3263541Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3263541Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3263541Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3273542Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3273542Z ##[error]... 29 more

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3283505Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.IssueFilters

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3283505Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3283505Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3293560Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3293560Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3293560Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3303542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3303542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3303542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3313551Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3313551Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3324709Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3324709Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3333606Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3333606Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3333606Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3343581Z ##[error]... 43 more

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3343581Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.IgnoreIssuesFilter

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3353529Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3353529Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3363526Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3363526Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3363526Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3373528Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3373528Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3383536Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3383536Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3383536Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3393530Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3393530Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3403535Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3403535Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3403535Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3413601Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3413601Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3423537Z ##[error]... 57 more

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3423537Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.IssueExclusionPatternInitializer

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3423537Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3433539Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3433539Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3443544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3443544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3443544Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3453617Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3453617Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3463542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3463542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3463542Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3473524Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3473524Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3483533Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3483533Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3483533Z ##[error]... 73 more

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3493576Z ##[error]Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Exclusions > Issues : Invalid format. The first field does not define a resource pattern: ,csharpsquid:S134,*

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3493576Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.PatternDecoder.checkRegularLineConstraints(PatternDecoder.java:78)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3503528Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.AbstractPatternInitializer.initPatterns(AbstractPatternInitializer.java:73)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3503528Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.AbstractPatternInitializer.<init>(AbstractPatternInitializer.java:41)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3513586Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.IssueExclusionPatternInitializer.<init>(IssueExclusionPatternInitializer.java:39)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3513586Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3513586Z 22:18:22.213 DEBUG: Execution getVersion

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3523565Z 22:18:22.214 DEBUG: Execution stop

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3523565Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3523565Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3533573Z ##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3533573Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3543563Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3543563Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3543563Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3563531Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3563531Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3573533Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3573533Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3573533Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3583572Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3583572Z ##[error]... 87 more

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3583572Z ##[error]22:18:22.213 ERROR:

2017-07-26T05:18:22.3593679Z ##[error]22:18:22.213 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: To eliminate any possibility that it would come from server side, could you open `http://<your SQ server>/batch/project?key=<your project key>` in a web browser, and look at the `settingsByModule` section (this is JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Somewhere* you have an exclusion defined. It's not likely to be defined in the UI. Aside from the fact that you've already looked there, the UI would enforce that all 3 parts are supplied.

[Places to look](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Additional+Analysis+Parameters):

- command line arguments - okay, this one's not likely either, but for thoroughness, these are the extra `/d:sonar.x=y` values on your analysis command line
- SonarQube.Analysis.xml - the path to this file would be passed on the command line with `/s:path`. It's used to share parameter values among projects
- .csproj file - look for a `<SonarQubeSetting>` element

Other places parameters can be set

- in the UI at project level: **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope**
- in the UI at the global level: **Administration > Analysis Scope**

Comment: Thanks G.Ann!! turns out it was a project level setting on the server, but after the database migration, the project is not showing on the dashboard so we did not suspect that. I went to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope on one of my projects and changed the url to use the failed project key and I am able to see some issue exclusions.